# Simple Multichoice, Multivariable, Calculator Query

Tags: c

I recently programmed this code (C) for a pretty simple calculator in Xcode.
It works mostly but does not display the answer for the sum/s.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

//int's & chars-----------------
char SumMethod;
int firstnumber, secondnumber;



//int's & chars------------------
    puts("Calculator v0.6");

printf("Please input first number: "); //Prompts 'firstnumber' input

scanf("%d", &firstnumber); //Scan's 'firstnumber' input and saves to '&firstnumber'

printf("Please input second number: "); //Prompts 'secondnumber' input
scanf("%d", &secondnumber); //Scan's 'secondnumber' input and saves to '&secondnumber
printf("d" "Please select Method: +(a), -(b), *(c), /(d): ");


    scanf("%c", &SumMethod);      //Scan's 'SumMethod' input









if(SumMethod=='a') {

    printf ("%d",firstnumber + secondnumber);       //This section detects the SumMethod and outputs the corrisponding sum
}
else if (SumMethod=='b'){

    printf("%d",firstnumber-secondnumber);
}

else if (SumMethod=='c') {
    printf("%d",firstnumber * secondnumber);
}

else if (SumMethod=='d') {
    printf("%d",firstnumber / secondnumber);
}
```

}

For the solution i'm looking for a response that doesn't drastically change the code as how it is now is what I understand and because i'm relatively new to coding in general however if there is an obvious fix using useful common tools that would be much appreciated.
Thanks, Xenon

Comment: How would i fix this?

Comment: Would i use the 'static' command?

Comment: Changed it to this and it automatically stops the program before I can select the; +,-,*,/ ..? ^updated code in post^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your comparisons are wrong. You need to compare your input to the LETTER a and not the (undefined and essentially random) values of the variables a,b,c,d.

so it is

```
if(SumMethod=='a')
```

instead of

```
if(SumMethod==a)
```

You don't need your variables a,b,c,d at all.

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested and still doesn't work..? I use the a,b,c,d to determine the sign used in the equation. Thats why i use the int's:                                                                            int a = firstnumber+secondnumber;
        int b = firstnumber-secondnumber;
        int c = firstnumber*secondnumber;
        int d = firstnumber/secondnumber;

Comment: I think you don't really understand. When you ask the user to input a/b/c/d you ask for a letter. The letter is 'a' and not a. The variable a (as opposed to the letter 'a') contains the sum of first number and second number. If the user enters 'a' the contents of SumMethod is 'a' and not the arbitrary content of the variable a. Example: first number 15, second 20. a will contain the value 35.  SumMethod contains 'a'. Or 97 as a number because that's the code for 'a').

Comment: So i made the changes you mentioned in the answer and still seems not to work posting new code above

Comment: I think i get it, so i would do scanf to detect the letter then set that to a variable which equals the +,-,*,/ But how would i do that?

Comment: It just tried it. The code works perfectly fine if you put the "please select method" and the scanf("%",&SumMethod") before the lines where you input the numbers. The problem if you put it after is that instead of the letter you catch the final "return" after the second number so SumMethod contains the code for return instead of getting the letter for the method.